# How to filter dates column with one condtion from the other column in Pyspark?

Tags: sql, pyspark

Assume, I have the following data frame named `table_df` in Pyspark

```
sid |    date     |  label
------------------
1033| 20170521    |  0
1033| 20170520    |  0
1033| 20170519    |  1
1033| 20170516    |  0
1033| 20170515    |  0
1033| 20170511    |  1
1033| 20170511    |  0
1033| 20170509    |  0
.....................
```

The data frame `table_df` contains different IDs in different rows, the above is simply one typical case of ID.

For each ID and for each date with label `1`,  I would like to find the date with label `0` that is the closest and before.

For the above table,  with `ID 1033`, `date=20170519`, `label 1`, the date of label 0 that is closest and before is `20170516`.

And with `ID 1033`, `date=20170511`, `label 1`, the date of label 0 that is closest and before is `20170509` .

So, finally using groupBy and some complicated operations, I will obtain the following table:

```
sid |    filtered_date  |
-------------------------
1033|  20170516         |  
1033|  20170509         |

-------------
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I tried but could not find any smart ways.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use window partition ordered by date and find difference with the next row,

```
df.show()
+----+--------+-----+
| sid|    date|label|
+----+--------+-----+
|1033|20170521|    0|
|1033|20170520|    0|
|1033|20170519|    1|
|1033|20170516|    0|
|1033|20170515|    0|
|1033|20170511|    1|
|1033|20170511|    0|
|1033|20170509|    0|
+----+--------+-----+
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
w = Window.partitionBy('sid').orderBy('date')


df.withColumn('diff',F.lead('label').over(w) - df['label']).where(F.col('diff') == 1).drop('diff').show()
+----+--------+-----+
| sid|    date|label|
+----+--------+-----+
|1033|20170509|    0|
|1033|20170516|    0|
+----+--------+-----+
```